# Return rows where the string contains a numeric value anywhere in the string - SQL - GBQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to select all table names from a GBQ dataset where the table name contains any numbers in any position and to then remove the RESULT_ prefix from any table names that have the prefix (not all the tables do, so a simple character deletion doesn't work here)

E.G.

**Table names**

- RESULT_Table_1
- RESULT_Table_2_new
- Table_Three
- Table_4_of_Four

Returns

- Table_1
- Table_2_new
- Table_4_of_Four

Here is how I am achieving this at present

```
SELECT REPLACE(table_name, 'RESULT_','')
as table_names
FROM project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_name
LIKE '%0%'
OR table_name
LIKE '%1%'
OR table_name
LIKE '%2%'
OR table_name
LIKE '%3%'
OR table_name
LIKE '%4%'
OR table_name
LIKE '%5%'
OR table_name
LIKE '%6%'
OR table_name
LIKE '%7%'
OR table_name
LIKE '%8%'
OR table_name
LIKE '%9%'
```

Is there a more robust (more elegant) way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(table_name, '^RESULT_', '') as table_name
FROM project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(t.table_name, '[0-9]';
```

Comment: Hi, that's a lot better than what I had! I spent ages looking for a way to do this with regular expressions and never came across those two functions (maybe I didn't look hard enough :P) Thanks!